# Preventing duplicate jquery animation when triggered by click vs. after a certain duration

Tags: jquery, events, animation, click

I have a notification bar that appears at the top of a page, then does a slideOut after xx seconds. I also have an icon that can be clicked to hasten the slideOut.

The problem is if the button is pressed the animation happens twice. Disappears on click then after xx seconds, it appears and does the slideOut again.

I imagine I need to write this differently to perhaps bind the events? Or do I need to add an if statement?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {
  hideNotification.defer(7000);
});
var hideNotification = function () {
  Ext.get('notification-bar').slideOut('t', {duration:0.5, easing:'easeOut'});
  Ext.get('notification-hide-button').setDisplayed(false);
}
$("#notification-hide-button").click(function() {
  hideNotification();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use window.setTimeout function..like that

```
var hideTimeout = window.setTimeout(hideNotification, 700);
```

and then add to the hideNotification function this

```
window.clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
```

that should remove the deferred call of your method once you click button..

Comment: Thanks - this worked after a little tinkering. I didn't need to use window. or didn't need to set a var. I used: hideTimeout = window.setTimeout(hideNotification, 700); and then:     clearTimeout(hideTimeout);

Comment: you actually dont need to use the var keyword, but that means, you are creating a global variable..
In other words, its better to add this, but notice that if you create local variable, its only visible for the function/object where it has been created.
That might have been your problem, you propably had been trying to acces variable while it was set in any other function with the var keyword..